# Highchart - How to set minWidth on stacked bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am having troubles trying to render Highchart inside a div. I dont know why there are bars that not displaying correctly.

I set a width value on the container highchart div, expecting bars occupy 100% of the div, but as you see it is not happening.

Here is how i set Highchart options:

```html
var chart =  new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                spacingBottom: 1,
                spacingTop: 1,
                spacingRight: 1,
                backgroundColor: null,
                renderTo: containerId
            },
            colors: ['#8b878a', '#10914E', '#DBD311', '#7e8b00'],
            title: '',
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels:{
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                labels:{
                    enabled: false
                },
                gridLineWidth:0,
                title: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                visibility: false
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
           plotOptions: {
            series: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function() {
                         if(this.series.options.showPercentageValue && this.series.options.percentageValue > minValueBarPercentage){
                          return (Math.round(this.series.options.percentageValue) + ' %'); //~~(elimina decimales)
                         }
                        },
                        style:{fontSize: '9px', color:'black',  paddingBottom: '1px', fontWeight: 'bold'}
                    },
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    groupPadding: 0.1
                }
            }, 
            series: values
        });
```

Any idea?

Comment: What does values look like?  Can you create a working jsfiddle?

Comment: There is no property as minWidth - you can use another series to complete the first one and set max x axis - see example http://jsfiddle.net/2vuhhdm6/

Comment: Here is the jdfiddle representing my problem http://jsfiddle.net/2vuhhdm6/5/

As you see, i want to render different highcharts on different divs, and i want them ending up at same point, to align them.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird could you see it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture of what is happening >>> https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXXcF.jpg